# No Sound Using Ubuntu 12.10 on Toshiba Satellite P100

Tags: sound, soundcard, speakers

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, and I'm not getting any sound from my Toshiba Satellite P100's internal speakers. I have an Intel NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller, and it's recognized by the system when I type lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio" into the CLI. My sound card is also listed in the Ubuntu sound card matrix, so it should be supported. I have master volume and speaker volume both turned up, as well as the volume knob on the front of my laptop, but still I get no sound.

Any thoughts? I'm new to Linux OS and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. open your start menu, go to media playback, go down to PulseAudio volume control. go to output devices sand click the little speaker icon to the left of the green checkmark at the top left corner of the window. hope this helps!

Comment: That would be for Ubuntu **10.x** or **11.x** ..